# Обстоятельства, выраженные существительными

Tags: запятые

Не могу разобраться с запятой:

**При заказе аналогичного комбо вновь (,) вы получите эти товары по такой же стоимости, как не изменится и общая цена комбо.**

Понимаю, состав предложения стоит совсем изменить, но сейчас нам важно разобраться именно с запятой.

**Правило гласит:**
обстоятельства, выраженные существительными в формах косвенных падежей с предлогами, обособляются только в случае попутного пояснения или смыслового выделения.

Сайты по проверке пунктуации (коим нельзя верить на 100%) убирают запятую, но есть ощущение, что она нужна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этом предложении несколько нарушен порядок слов. Решение не в положении запятой:

«При заказе аналогичного комбо вы вновь получите товары по той же стоимости, при этом  общая цена комбо не изменится».

*Вновь*, как и другие определительные наречия (*снова*, *опять*, *после*) не являются вводными словами.